# Get max value from a json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, max

This is my data

```
var data = [{
    "name": "abc",
    "cap": 12
}, {
    "name": "pqr",
    "cap": 10
}, {
    "name": "xyz",
    "cap": 50
}
```

Now here I want to get max value of "cap" i.e `50`.
Is there any function to do so.
Something like `max(data['cap'])` ?

Thanks

Domnick

Comment: There is a way, can you show your try?

Comment: `Math.prototype.max( null, data.map( s => s.cap  )  )`

Comment: @Learnonhardway That is a little bit of a foolish comment, lol.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you're after the largest 'cap' only, you could use 'Math.max' if you're after the object with the largest 'cap' you could use 'sort' to order the array by 'cap' or 'reduce' to purely get the largest object. What are you after?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Math.max(...data.map( s => s.cap ))

Comment: @AndrewBone yep, that's better as it's less verbose.

Comment: Reduce example: `data.reduce((m, n) => m.cap > n.cap ? m : n, data[0])`. Sort example: `data.slice(0).sort((a, b) => b.cap - a.cap)[0]`. If you're after ONLY the max cap then either @gurvinder372 or @Andrew_Bone have nice concise examples.

Comment: Actually I m using data to generate a chart using plotly. and was trying to make the range dynamic, that's the reason I was trying to first calculate the max to select it as an upper range in the axes